# How to pass in values to an array one element at a time in Interactive C

Tags: c, arrays

I understand that in C we can do

```
int foo[3];
foo[0]=1;
foo[1]=2;
foo[2]=3;
```

However in Interactive C, it gives me an error. I can only declare everything at once, such as

```
int foo[3] ={1,2,3};
```

Anyone familiar with Interactive C knows why is this the case? Is that in IC, you cannot pass in value one by one at all?

Comment: Correction: Be careful NOT to access foo[3] at a length of 3! Arrays are Zero-Based!

Comment: Just for clarification: By "Interactive C" you mean [this](http://www.botball.org/ic)?

Comment: @EGOrecords Thanks, it was a typo. just corrected it.

Comment: @Joe It won't compile, it says syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason it gave me an error is because the declared more int variables after the array assignment. For example,

```
...
foo[5] = 1;
foo[6] = 2;

int bar = 3;
```

This will not compile, it will highlight the "int bar" line and shows a syntax error.

seems like one cannot declare more variables with their types after the array assignment.

This might due to the fact that IC is an simplified version of C.